# Asp.net mvc highlighting a field

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a form with 2 input controls. On click of a button a service call is made. If service returns an error i need to highlight the respective input control. Is there any way to set modelstate of a model property to false. Or is there any other way to achieve this.

So like on click of a button, a service call is made AddPerson with name and age. The service returns an error PersonName already exists. In controller i get the errorCode "PersonAlreadyExist" to highlight the Person name textbox. Now how to use this to hightlight the textbox.

Comment: Have you looked at ModelState.AddModelError ?

Comment: Show some code!. Are you doing a normal submit? You can use the `[Remote]` attribute in conjunction with `@HtmlValidationMessageFor()` to do all this client side, otherwise use `ModelState.AddModelError()` and return the view.

Comment: Thnx daniel.. Stephen..Yeah the ModelState.AddModelError("Name","") did resolved the issue.. Now the problem I am facing is I need to define type of error. Like warning/error type. Is there any way to do this